# EMG amplifier using LM358

Tags: arduino, amplifier, biopotential

I came up with the following simple schematic in order to amplify the EMG signal and feed it to an arduino:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx9SMf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is that I monitor analog pin 6 of the arduino and it's always 0.

Comment: Is this a serious question or a thanksgiving prank?

Comment: Is Arduino input A6 connected directly to ground (as shown in the schematic)? That's why it measures as 0.

Comment: @MarkU Sorry that was a mistake (and one more), just edited it.

Comment: @JohnD Yes it is a serious question and yes I know the schematic is probably bad. I am just trying to make it work.

Comment: Your schematic shows no DC path for the LM358 negative input. Also there are safety issues when connecting electronics to people.  That is why there are strict regulations on medical equipment and one reason such equipment is expensive.

Comment: You have no negative feedback.  This will saturate.

Comment: You need a gain of about 500, not 10

Comment: How is the lm358 powered?

Comment: @ScottSeidman I power it with a usb cable.

Comment: Simply put, you're not going to amplify EMG with a single op amp.  You will need at least an instrumentation amp and an op amp, and you'll have to provide a mid rail reference voltage.  I suggest searching for EMG on this site.

Comment: OK, sorry, the output was shorted to ground, there was no negative feedback, and there was no DC path for bias current in the original schematic, so I thought it might be a joke.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I lost you on "provide a mid rail reference voltage". Do you mean I need -/+ voltage?

Comment: @DimChtz  not quite.  Again, you should search for emg on this site.  You're very far away from a circuit that will do what you need it to, and your circuit is not a starting point at all.  Put in your research, then take a stab at it, and post your efforts.  When you get closer, you'll be able to understand the help you get.